# How to read a key value after decoding json in erlang

Tags: json, erlang, jiffy

Here is a short query

In Erlang I parsed json using

```
Ccode = jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>).
```

it returns

```
{[{<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>}]}
```

Now target is to get value of 'foo' and it should return 'bar'

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a list of attributes of the JSON object using pattern matching and then find a value by a key in the resulting list:

```
{Attrs} = jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>),
FooValue = proplists:get_value(<<"foo">>, Attrs).
```

Comment: Rubber Cthulhu..... this works fine on my shell, I am willing to use jiffy in a ejabberd module, do you have you any idea on that, if I need to include something in .erl file, because I am getting unknown function.

Answer (score 3):

I find [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) easy to use:

```
Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> Data = jsx:decode(<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>).
[{<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>}]
2> proplists:get_value(<<"foo">>, Data).
<<"bar">>
```

You can even parse it into [Maps](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html).

```
3> Map = jsx:decode(<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>, [return_maps]).
#{<<"foo">> => <<"bar">>}
4> maps:get(<<"foo">>, Map).
<<"bar">>
```

Comment: Just to add, you can make jiffy decode to maps using the 'return_maps' option.

Comment: That is true! `#{<<"foo">> => <<"bar">>} = jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>, [return_maps]).`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ej](https://github.com/seth/ej) module:

> The ej module makes it easier to work with Erlang terms representing JSON in the format returned by jiffy, mochijson2, or ejson. You can use ej:get/2 to walk an object and return a particular value, ej:set/3 to update a value within an object, or ej:delete/2 to remove a value from an object.